# ASP.NET MVC How to Use two Actionresults with Html.BeginForm?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to do the same as this [ASP.NET MVC Using two inputs with Html.BeginForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953285/asp-net-mvc-using-two-inputs-with-html-beginform) question describes but with enough difference that I don't really know hwo to apply it on my project:

I have a view that has 3 dropdownlists(profilelist, connected salarylist & not connected salarylist)

Looks like this:

```
  <div class="row bgwhite">
           @using (Html.BeginForm("GetConnectedSalaries", "KumaAdmin", FormMethod.Get, new { Id = "ProfileListForm" }))
            {
              <div class="four columns list list1">
                  @Html.DropDownList("Profiles", (SelectList) ViewBag.Profiles, "--Välj profilgrupp--",
                  new 
                  {
                    //onchange = "$('#ProfileListForm')[0].submit();"
                    // Submits everytime a new element in the list is chosen
                    onchange = "document.getElementById('ProfileListForm').submit();"
                  })
              </div>
            }
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "KumaAdmin", FormMethod.Get, new { Id = "SalaryListForm" }))
            {
                <div class="four columns list list2" style="margin-top:-19px;">
                    @Html.DropDownList("Salaries", (SelectList) ViewBag.Salaries, "--Kopplade LöneGrupper--") 
                </div>
            }

            @using (Html.BeginForm("GetNOTConnectedSalaries", "KumaAdmin", FormMethod.Get, new { Id = "NotConSalaryListForm" }))
            {
                <div class="four columns list list2" style="margin-top:-19px;">
                    @Html.DropDownList("Salaries", (SelectList)ViewBag.NotConSalaries, "--Ej Kopplade LöneGrupper--") 
                    <input style="float: left;" type="submit" value="Knyt" />
                </div>
            }
         </div>
```

as you can see above when i change an element i the profile list i have script code that submits the form and calls the following actionresult that populates my "connected salarylist".

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetConnectedSalaries(int Profiles = -1)
    {
        Model.SalaryGroups = AdminManager.GetConnectedSalaries(Profiles);
        ViewBag.Salaries = new SelectList(Model.SalaryGroups, "Id", "SalaryName", "Description");

        return (Index());
    }
```

What I wan't to do:

When I chose a element in the profilelist i would like to call 2 actionresults, the one that i have shown above AND a second one that will populare my third list that will contain "not connected salaries". 
Second Actionresult:

```
 public ActionResult GetNOTConnectedSalaries(int Profiles = -1)
    {
        Model.SalaryGroups = AdminManager.GetNOTConnectedSalaries(Profiles);
        ViewBag.NotConSalaries = new SelectList(Model.NotConSalaryGroups, "Id", "SalaryName", "Description");

        return (Index());
    }
```

I don't want to do this with AJAX/JSON, strictly MVC.
I read the question that i linked above but did not know how to apply it to my project or if it is even possible to do the same.

If more info is needed ask and i will do my best to provide it.

Thank you!

Comment: why not put logic of both the action in  in a single action, as technically only a single action is taking place at client side though you want to return two results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was so sure that the best way to do this was to have two actionresults that i was totaly blinded to the soloution that i could call both my db methods from the same actionresult and populate both of the lists.

Simple soloution:

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetSalaries(int Profiles = -1)
    {
        Model.SalaryGroups = AdminManager.GetConnectedSalaries(Profiles);
        ViewBag.Salaries = new SelectList(Model.SalaryGroups, "Id", "SalaryName", "Description");
        Model.NotConSalaryGroups = AdminManager.GetNOTConnectedSalaries(Profiles);
        ViewBag.NotConSalaries = new SelectList(Model.NotConSalaryGroups, "Id", "SalaryName", "Description");

        return (Index());
    }
```

Sorry if I wasted your time:( but hopefully this will help others that attempt the same.

However if there is a way to do this in two actionresults then I will leave the question as open, would be interesting to see how it is done.